# Ustream API not working?

Tags: javascript, html, api

i am using this code to get my ustream status.

```
    <font color='red'><span id="status">status</span></font>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function set_status(status)
    {
    if (status == "offline")
    {    

    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML =
    "offline";
    }
    else if (status == "live")
    {    
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML =
    "LIVE";
    }
    else
    {    
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML  =
    "Error getting stream status!";
    }
    }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://api.ustream.tv/html/channel/codtelevision/getValueOf/status?key=MY KEY CODE=set_status">
    </script>
```

for some reason nothing happens. I am using jsfiddle.net for my testing..if that helps. here is a link to my code:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SPwvx/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JSFiddle, Javascript comments use `//` or `/*` `*/` comments, not `<!--` `-->`. This results in a syntax error which causes the code to be ignored.

After removing the comments, you get:

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

Comment: i deleted them all, but still got nothing, it still says status and not offline..also, if this helps, all i have where i say key here...is my code, nothing else

Comment: I do not have an API key for testing.